Same Object_ID in two different databases via sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
How is it possible that ObjectID 885578193 is in two different databases?  Please see the screenshot included.
SELECT
    DB_NAME(Database_id) AS DBName
    , OBJECT_NAME(Object_id) AS TableName
    ,  *
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE DB_NAME(Database_id) NOT LIKE 'Master%'
    AND NOT DB_NAME(Database_id) = 'msdb'
ORDER BY DBName, TableName;

ObjectID
I was expecting ObjectID 885578193 to only show in the Udemy database.

OBJECT_ID is unique per-database: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46636/which-is-the-uniqueness-level-of-object-id

object_id isn't guaranteed to be unique in sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats even within the same database, either: since tables and views can have multiple indexes their object_id can appear multiple times.

object_id is very likely to be shared across databases as it is just based off an incrementation logic from the previous object_id allocated in the database and so all databases are going round on the same cycle.
(Each object_id in user databases is (CAST(previous_allocated_object_id AS BIGINT) + 16000057) % 2147483648)
You should pass the database_id second parameter to OBJECT_NAME
i.e. Use
SELECT database_id, 
       OBJECT_NAME(Object_id, database_id) AS ObjectName
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats

Do not use
SELECT database_id, 
       OBJECT_NAME(Object_id) AS ObjectName
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats

